# Android - changing ImageView drawable after scales & translate animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I have an app that shows thumbnails of images presented as ImageViews. You tap on an image, it animates to fill the screen (rotating 90 degrees on the way if it's not a portrait image). Once it's full screen I want to switch the underlying bitmap in the ImageView with a higher res version that I'm downloading off the internet.

The problem is that after the ImageView has been scaled, the new bitmap image appears on top of the old one and at the size of the thumbnail.

Any ideas?

Comment: ImageView can only display one image, so either you have set one of the images as the background and the other as the actual image, or something is done in your loading. Please post some code of how you load the image and apply it to the view.

Comment: You can do some thing like onclick of the image you can animate an image form the user selected position (increase the image width and height also) after resizing the image set the high res bitmap as the source to the image, when you want to show the image list, reverse the animation and make the visiblity of the animating image gone. hope this will help